# Installing POD driver for Symfony on Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and would like to try it, but I can't seem to find out what the deal is with this "POD Driver" is and how to install it. I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean PDO driver? This a generic layer for database connections and should be already installed with the specific database driver.

for mysql it's installed with the `php5-mysql` package.